# Localnotification alert sound in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alert, localnotification

Is it really not possible to let my local notification sound ring when the phone is locked?
I want my local notification give sound even if my phone is locked!
another question i searched alot why my local notification doesn't appear on the lock screen?

Comment: I think you don’t understand how notifications work. The appearance is customizable. Go to the *Settings->Notifications->YourApp*

Comment: i already did this

Answer (score 0):

If you added the sound permission when requesting then it should have the sound when it comes , even when the screen is locked/Sound Muted it will appear , and here is a [tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/push-notifications-local-notifications-tutorial/) that you can give a try

Comment: it only give me sound if the phone is not locked!